# JMeter does not save values of previous drop downs

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jmeter

I am using JMeter for testing of my web application.

I have attached two images.

[FirstInstance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxlmy.png)
The FirstInstance is when I run the test for the first time and there are only 3 drop downs created with values filled in it
But when I run the test second time for the same user it should of course take in the previously created drop downs and it does, but JMeter does not take in the value from the previous drop down due to which I face problem when the script proceeds to the next step
[SecondInstance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4PX2.png)
In the SecondInstance we can see 6 drop downs (first three from the latest test and last three from the previous test) of which 3 of them do not have values but in the database the values are present.

Kindly help.

Regards,
Prasad Iyer

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does**

My expectation is that your test is probably missing some JavaScript-driven request which isn't simply present or it doesn't work due to missing or incorrectly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations).

---

I normally use the next troubleshooting approach: I record requests which are being sent from JMeter and from the real browser with a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare them. The idea is that the requests should be **the same** (apart from dynamic parameters values), if they are not - there is an issue with JMeter test which needs to be fixed as well-behaved test must mimic real application usage as close as possible.